# Paging in a long chart

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I am no excel expert, and couldn't find an answer from the search

I have a bar chart with about 200 items on the Horizontal axis and want to have paging option with 10 each on a page

is it possible? please tell me it is  :-(

Comment: I don't think you can do this without a macro

Comment: any documentation / example you can give me?

Comment: Why not create 20 spreadsheets with a bar chart on each one, then pull in the datapoints using formulas? That's one way to technically have "pages"

Comment: The functionality you want is a project to develop. [Here is an example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-creating-a-scrolling-excel-chart/)